# My MacBook Pro is not sleeping when I close the lid on battery

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, battery

I purchased my macbook back in 2011, and this problem just started. When I unplug and close my computer to put it in my backpack for school, it does not sleep. I take it out and its very hot and has lost a large amount of battery. My energy saver controls say it should sleep after 10 minutes of inactivity, but either way it should sleep when I close the lid. I don't have any sharing options checked or any running apps that should be keeping it awake so I have no idea what could be causing this

Comment: Please add the OS X version in your original question.

Comment: it's a bug of El capitan i think

Comment: If anyone has the same problem, please tell on which version of MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a look at this answer which indicates the commands to help you analyse if any process is [blocking the sleep of your MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/77426/22003).
2. If nothing is blocking it, then look at :

   ```
   egrep -i 'sleep|wake' /var/log/kernel.log
   ```

   and look if you see a sleep line at the time you close the lid. If you don't, look at any information message in:

   ```
   /var/log/kernel.log
   ```

   around the instant this event should have happened.
3. Create a test account, close your session, and open one with this test account. Is your MacBook entering sleep when you close the lid?

Comment: I couldn't identify anything keeping it from sleeping, but now I notice that even if I hit the power button and click sleep on the window that pops up, it won't go to sleep. I'm thinking that I am going to have to reinstall OSX

Comment: What does happen with a test account?

Comment: → grgarside: thank you for cleaning my presentation ;).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can reinstall OSX without using a disk and its fairly quick. This fixed my issue

Comment: And after this reinstall of OSX, what will avoid you to get this problem again?

Answer (score -1):

I have a MacBook Pro 13" A1278 (Mid-2010). I had the same problem. When I closed the lid, the screen remained on wouldn't shut off but I could manually put it to sleep from the Apple menu. Now keep in mind this all happened with no battery in the laptop. I just put in a new battery tonight and voila! Sleep mode works again!! I troubleshooted for hours. No more worrying about the power cable falling out.